# CMS Orchard's action low performance

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, profiling, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I am trying to understand why our CMS Orchard is performing very low with our Web application. I took an example of the Edit action... Here is the code and the profiler

```
namespace Orchard.Core.Contents.Controllers {
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public class AdminController : Controller, IUpdateModel {

        //...

        public ActionResult Edit(int id) {
            var contentItem = _contentManager.Get(id, VersionOptions.Latest);

            if (contentItem == null)
                return HttpNotFound();

            if (!Services.Authorizer.Authorize(Permissions.EditContent, contentItem, T("Cannot edit content")))
                return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();

            var model = _contentManager.BuildEditor(contentItem);
            return View(model);
        }

        //...
}
```

[image]

We have some Web API, named FrontServices, Orchard uses to update data in the Oracle DB, but these actions does not seem to take much time...

The AdminControler.Edit is taking a lot of time, that maybe because of the threads or other things... maybe because of Authentication... I don't know exactly what code from the controller takes so much time, did someone experienced such kind of problems with this CMS?

[image]

Comment: That's highly unusual. I don't see much on that profile that could give a definitive answer, but it seems like at least a large part of it is spent on some external web request that, yes, looks to be authentication. What kind of auth are you using? Did you try to switch that to the basic default auth, for testing?

Comment: how should it look like? :")

Comment: How should what look like?